# Check if popup window is already open

Tags: javascript

How can I modify this so it checks and if a popup window is already open?

```
function popUp(URL) {
  day = new Date();
  id = day.getTime();
  eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=350,height=100');");
}
```

> /////////////Edit No2

`var options = "toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=350,height=100";`

`var popup = window.open(URL, "popup", options);`

`function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=350,height=100');");
}`

> My js call

`<a id="floating_link" href="javascript:popUp('MyPage.html')">Player</a>`

Comment: noooooooooooo!!!!!!!!!!!!! eval #ftf!

Comment: It isn't an http callback, its just using local variables. This looks like a pretty safe use of eval. Relax.

Comment: @Travis, Yes I see, but still...

Comment: Eval bad!!! window["page" + id] = window.open(URL, id, 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=350,height=100');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311104/check-when-browser-popup-window-has-been-closed) question linked to here.

Check the following code.

You can use [onbeforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) to get a callback before the window unloads.

To check if this is due to `window.close` do this

```
setTimeout(function(){
        if(anc.closed) console.log('closed'); 
        else console.log('refreshed');
  },1000); // to check after the window closed
```

**FULL CODE**

```
var anc = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com');

var anc.onbeforeunload = function() { // called before closing the window.

  setTimeout(function() {
    if (anc.closed) console.log('closed');
    else console.log('refreshed');
  }, 1000); // to check after the window closed

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `id` for the window, which is the name of the window, to reuse it if it exists.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```
var options = "toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=350,height=100";
var popup = window.open(URL, "popup", options);
```

To do this with an anchor tag you just set the `target`

If you set an anchor tag's target `target="myopup"` it will use that same window if it exists

Comment: No haven't been able to make it work. Would you have another recommendation Hunter. It would be nice if the button on the main page could toggle also...

Comment: @jbabey - really? Downvote for a post over a year ago? If you even bothered to check the link and the content you would see that it is accurate, regardless of the source.