# Without reloading bring to view page

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-ui

Click from parent window open a child window using window.open("url","name").If again clicked the parent for opening the child window then check if the child window is already opened.if it is already opened then bring to view that page without reloading otherwise open in new window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the popup window using window.open() itself then check this thread

[Check if a popup window is already open before opening it using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882112/check-if-a-popup-window-is-already-open-before-opening-it-using-jquery)

There is a better alternative to do this by using Jquery Dialog:

Just put a div in the parent window which will act as the container for the popup contents and check whether it is visible or not.

Comment: when i clicked button then open a url using window.open(url).and some actions are done in that window.if again i click then show that page without reloading what changes i done.if not opend then only open the new tab