# Check when browser popup window has been closed

Tags: javascript

If I create a window in JavaScript with `var windowRef = window.open(//...)` how do I check when windowRef has been closed?

Comment: FYI, You'll only be able to do this if the URL you open is on the same domain.

Comment: check this answer of mine in the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137297/check-if-popup-window-is-already-open/44311587#44311587